# How to insert an image at a specific location

Tags: floats, sectioning, placeins

I have two figures, each of them is as large as an entire page. I have started the section, let's say on page 1. After 1/2 page of an introduction, I start the first subsection. This subsection pretty much fills 2 pages. I am now on the middle of page 3. I start the second subsection, which fills little more than a page. On page 4, however, I want to show figure 1. I want the second subsection to continue on page 5. On page 6, I want to show figure 2.

This little sketch summarizes what I have just said:

```
Section 
  Subsection 1 (Start at Page 0.5)
  Subsection 2 (Start at Page 2.5)
  Figure 1 (Page 4)
  Subsection 2 (End at Page 5)
```

Now, for some reason this seems to be impossible. I am using a simple figure environment to include the figure. I include the `\usepackage[section]{placeins}` package in my .cls. And ya, I have found an answer here on stackexchange how to adopt this section placeins to subsections as well. But that's not what I want. I want to start subsection 2, but then include my figure, and then continue with the subsection. I mean, come on, there has got to be a way, right?

Comment: you can have the figure on whatever page you want but it's not possible to guess what your input is like from the description here. Please make a small complete example that shows the problem (you can use lipsum package to generate filler text and `\includegraphics[height=....,width=\textwidth]{example-image}` as an image in your example.

Comment: you say what you want is impossible, but you don't say what output you get or where the figure appears, nor do you say where the figure is in your source.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I see, you're right. It was a bit ill posted. Your answer, however, is exactly what I was looking for. Quite surprising for me that I don't have to add any positioning options. .. next time I will try and use the dummy-text example that you mentioned. thx for that!

Comment: the figure options are for _reducing_ the places where a float may go.  for example if you use `[tb]` the main effect of that is to prevent the float appearing on a page on its own as `p` is omitted. (I would guess the code that you did not show was doing something like that?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question isn't at all clear (what is page 0.5, if it means half way down page 1; what is page 2.5?, half way down page 2 or page 3?) and you have subsection 2 twice. But I *think* you are asking for this layout

[image]

with subsection headings on pages 1,2,5 and full page floats on pages 4 and 6.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{zzz one}
\lipsum[1]
\lipsum[2-5]
\subsection{zzz two}
\lipsum[1-5]
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  
\rule{5cm}{15cm}

  \caption{a figure}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[6-8]\lipsum[2-4]
\subsection{zzz three}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  
\rule{5cm}{15cm}

  \caption{a figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I haven't used any special or non standard commands to position the figures, just let latex's normal float handling position them.